# How to create a color box in the pdf using HTML CSS

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf and I have to create a box with a number. I tried `display:block` but it's not supporting tcpdf.

My expected output is this

[image]

But I am getting like this

[image]

I am using below code

```
$html='<div  style="text-align:center;">
       <p><span style="color:#fff ; width: 150px;height: 100px;background-color: #2ecc71;line-height: 100px;">46%</span></p>
       </div>';
```

Comment: use `$html.=` and let me know.

Comment: @KUMAR, that Dot(.) is not the issue. I am able to access my variable.

Comment: Try your HTML in jsfiddle or something similar. The issue is not tcpdf, it's that your HTML styling isn't correct. If you put your width / height / background color on your div element, you'll have a lot better luck.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche, Apologizes for the late reply, I just saw your comment. I found the solution using a table. Let me know if you know the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and experiment, I found my solution, I don't know it is the best solution or not but it's solved my issue.

I used the below code to get my expected output. I used a table because there is some limitations in tcpdf for css. Also i used `width="80px" height="80px"` instead of inside inline style.

```html
<table style="text-align:center;">
  <tr>
    <td width="80px" height="80px" style="background-color: #2ecc71;color:#fff;line-height: 80px;font-size:30px;text-align:center">46%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```